# High loss from convolutional autoencoder keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, convolution, autoencoder

I am training a convolutional autoencoder and I am having trouble getting the loss to decrease and was hoping someone could point out some possible improvements.

I have greyscale images of 1024x1024 (I've tried the same thing with 512x512 too) and I'm hoping to compress them for unsupervised clustering. My full model is below but it follows a pretty basic pattern of several Conv2D layers w/ max pooling, followed by a dense layer, then reshape and Conv2D layers back up to the original image size.

Some things I've tried so far:

1) I found that mse worked better as a loss function than binary cross entropy, because the pixel luminosity values are so far from evenly distributed (binary cross entropy gets stuck assigning everything to a value of 1, which has low error but isn't useful).

2) I can easily achieve very low error and near perfect (to my eye at least) image reconstruction if I just get rid of the dense layer in the middle and compress the image slightly less. This is fairly obvious, but I guess it shows that I'm not making some kind of error resulting in nonsense outputs.

3) My loss doesn't really get below 0.02-0.03. Still, at 0.025 or so the image is reconstructed enough that it's obvious that the output is coming from the input, not some kind of random noise (like making every pixel the same intensity or something). I think getting it below 0.01 would be enough that I can cluster on. My lowest (albeit on a slightly easier subset of my data) was 0.018 and I could see clear clustering in samples when I plotted my encoded values in a heatmap.

4) I get a lot of dying ReLUs when my middle dense layer uses a ReLU activation, which makes it less useful for the eventual clustering. I use tanh instead. I also found that "he_normal" works better as an initialization for the dense layer.

5) Adding more dense layers in the middle doesn't seem to help at all.

6) Reversing the shape of the encoder (so that it goes from fewer kernels per layer to more kernels) doesn't help either, even though I know that's traditionally how a convolutional autoencoder looks.

Here is the full model (the output from model.summary()

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         (None, 1024, 1024, 1)     0       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_40 (Conv2D)           (None, 1024, 1024, 128)   1280      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_19 (MaxPooling (None, 512, 512, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 512, 512, 128)     512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_41 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 512, 64)      73792
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPooling (None, 256, 256, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_42 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 32)      18464
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_21 (MaxPooling (None, 128, 128, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_43 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 16)      4624      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_22 (MaxPooling (None, 64, 64, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_44 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 8)         1160      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPooling (None, 32, 32, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 8192)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 512)               4194816   
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_4 (Reshape)          (None, 8, 8, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_22 (UpSampling (None, 16, 16, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_45 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 16)        1168      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_23 (UpSampling (None, 32, 32, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_46 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 16)        2320      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_24 (UpSampling (None, 64, 64, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_47 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_25 (UpSampling (None, 128, 128, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_48 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 64)      18496
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_26 (UpSampling (None, 256, 256, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_49 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_27 (UpSampling (None, 512, 512, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_50 (Conv2D)           (None, 512, 512, 128)     147584
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_28 (UpSampling (None, 1024, 1024, 128)   0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_51 (Conv2D)           (None, 1024, 1024, 1)     1153
=================================================================
Total params: 4,543,865
Trainable params: 4,543,609
Non-trainable params: 256
```

Comment: Have you tried using SELUs in the place of ReLUs?

Comment: To me, the encoder reconstruction sounds quite successful and the loss you're achieving is not high at all

Comment: I just tried switching to SELUs, with lecun_normal as the initializer, but the loss got much higher. Is there something else I have to change for it to work?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and wondering if you have solved this issue? Would you be so kind to share a bit more on the size of the filters you used for each convolution layer or if you have the code available somewhere?

Comment: I never really fixed it, but I got it down to a MSE loss of 0.015. Putting 2 more dense layers in the middle, connected with a residual connection helped. e.g.: 
<br/>
`flat1 = Dense(1024, activation = 'tanh', kernel_initializer = "he_normal",
        activity_regularizer = l2(0.001))(encoder)
<br/>
flat2 = Dense(1024, activation = 'tanh', kernel_initializer = "he_normal",
        activity_regularizer = l2(0.001))(flat1)
<br/>
encoder = keras.layers.add([flat1, flat2])`

Comment: That said, it ended up that I got pretty good clustering results without having my autoencoder get all that much better

Answer (score 0):

Your loss-function is likely the issue. Using BCE on Logit outputs of the network. Should solve the issue.

1. Use: `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`
2. Remove the activation functions from the last layers of both the Encoder & Decoder (Last dense layer of the Encoder, and last Conv layer of the Decoder should have no Activations.)

Note: When you're reconstructing from embeddings, add a sigmoid function to it.

```
z = encoder(x)
x_hat_raw = decoder(z)
reconstruction = sigmoid(x_hat_raw)
```

Should train well now!